# Does “everywhere and nowhere” mean “irrelevant”?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

An Italian student, a young man of twenty, came to me today with a bunch of papers in his bag. It was the questions and answers to a multiple choice English quiz. We're talking hundreds of questions. He needs to pass this exam *really well* if he has any hope of being accepted in a military academy.

We go through the questions and answers that he is unsure of until we reach this one…

> Choose the alternative which is closest in meaning to the word in brackets and which does not change the meaning of the sentence. **“The question is [irrelevant]”**
>
> [ ] not respectful
> [ ] hard to answer
> [ ] inappropriate
> [ ] very important
> [x] everywhere and nowhere

He reasoned that "inappropriate" was the best choice but the so-called correct answer is the one marked x. I don't think either one is right, the "correct" answer is an idiom with which I am most unfamiliar. The expression that I do *know* is **[“neither here nor there”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neither_here_nor_there)**

Wiktionary defines it

> Having no significance or influence on the question at hand.

The synonyms listed are: *beside the point, betwixt and between, **irrelevant**, unimportant, unrelated, impertinent*

But it has been many years since I lived in the UK, and maybe “everywhere and nowhere" is used nowadays. Google tells me it is the title of an English 2011 [film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1673374/), which suggests that the idiom(?) is used but it is not listed in any of the main dictionaries I consulted.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/everywhere)
[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english?q=everywhere%20and%20nowhere)
[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everywhere%20and%20nowhere)
[WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=everywhere%20and%20nowhere&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=)

[image: copy of a multiple choice self-study aid]

1. Is the answer “everywhere and nowhere” in the multiple choice quiz right or wrong?  Please provide supporting evidence.

Comment: Who prepared   the questions and answers?

Comment: @user240918 I don't know, I think someone from the military academy. There are a few other answers (literally three or four) which smell off to me but the rest are good.

Comment: I am UK native, and I have heard the expression "everywhere and nowhere", first of all in the lyrics of a pop song "Hi Ho Silver Lining" by Jeff Beck (1967) You're everywhere and nowhere, baby\That's where you're at\Going down a bumpy hillside\In your hippy hat (etc). I always heard it used to mean "severely disorganised, unworldly, spaced out, etc". I think this "correct" answer given (by whom?) does not mean "irrelevant", but neither do the others. The other answers are wildly wrong, this one is just, well, weird. Maybe the hundreds of questions are a test of the candidate's determination?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey the actual number of questions asked on the exam day is 60 so... he's doing his utmost to memorize all the answers. Some questions are really easy but a few are tough. This one sounded weird to me.

Comment: As far as I know, in multiple choice questions, one or more questions may have no correct answer!

Comment: @user240918 take a look at the question that follows the "irrelevant" one, among the options is "None of the other alternatives is a correct answer", so if there is no appropriate answer it is listed as a possibility but that can also be a red herring.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - what I’m saying is that they sometimes provide only “wrong” answers on purpose. I know they do it in exams like GMAT etc. “Everywhere and nowhere” may be just a tricky option.

Comment: @user240918 What do you mean? The vast majority are good, there are probably three or four which I find myself quibbling with although I haven't seen each and every question, it would take hours!

Comment: He's doing his best to _memorize_ the answers? Really? Isn't the way to score highly in multiple-choice tests to _know_ a sufficiently large number of correct answers?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I didn't mean to suggest that he didn't *know* anything, but the ones that are tricky and require a higher level of English he is memorizing. I help to explain the rules, and give him homework. He's a hard working lad, and if the exam included speaking I would fear the worst (he has a pretty bad accent) but otherwise, he's smart. The exam is in February.

Comment: Is it possible that the exam compiler has translated an Italian phrase equivalent to "neither here nor there" but done it literally? That could produce this sort of oddity.

Comment: @BoldBen actually there are traps laid open for Italian speakers, a few will  select the wrong grammar answer because in Italian it would be correct e.g. present tense instead of the Present Progressive. The questions cover a range of notions, phrasal verbs, idioms, proverbs, grammar, word order, orthography... and the answers supplied are, in the vast majority of cases, absolutely correct. There are only a few which have left me perplexed, and this is one of them. The phrase translated into Italian does not make sense, which explains the student's hesitancy and confusion.

Comment: One of the questions is about putting a cat among [a group of animals] and the options were "mice", "birds", "pigeons", and "butterflies". I haven't heard that in years but the answer selected is pigeons and there is no Italian equivalent of this idiom. Does knowing the answer mean your English is really good? F*ck no.

Comment: Strange to see anyone of your repute using a preamble like that but I agree with Michael Harvey’s *Hi Ho Silver Lining*. In 60 years of listening, I’ve never noticed any other use of that phrase. If I had, it would be hard to see it as relevant.

Your candidate is clearly correct; the answer is “inappropriate.”

I didn’t understand ‘neither is right…’ until ‘neither here nor there’ which I see as ‘irrelevant’ with no useful comparison to ‘everywhere and nowhere.’
Clearly the academy needs to understand that author was at best misguided, and change the exam.

Moire…

Comment: Further, how sure are you of the facts here?

I seem to remember you're in the USA and thus, powerless here. However, as an EU citizen I can ask my Member of the European Parliament to challenge this, and ask the academy to make it right.

Thus again, how sure are you of the facts?

Comment: Not an answer, as I have done no research and can't be bothered, but "everywhere and nowhere" is, in my experience, an evasive answer to the question "where have you been?". It has absolutely no connotation of "irrelevant" to me, a native BrE speaker.

Comment: This has just come to the top of the pile, and I'll add that I think no answer here is justifiable. 'Irrelevant' is a 'lower-level classmate' of 'inappropriate', but not a close enough synonym (a relevant question could be inappropriate because it is phrased too confrontationally, for instance). And I cannot imagine 'everywhere and nowhere'  being used other than as @Michael Harvey says (and I've never heard the expression other than in the Beck song).  I'd guess the setters confused this with the aforementioned 'That's neither here nor there'.

Answer (score 1):

I would have also picked *everywhere and nowhere* if forced to choose between those options. But I wouldn't have been happy about it.

Without actually looking at a thesaurus, when I hear the word *irrelevant* I think to myself *immaterial*, *unrelated*, *not useful*, *beside the point*, *off topic*, and *has no bearing*. Only one of those is what Wiktionary lists. Further, I would never associate *irrelevant* with *impertient*—so I find that synonym strange. (But that's just based on my personal associations.)

By the process of elimination, I immediately ruled out the first four possible answers. (Unlike the Italian student, I would never associate *irrelevant* with *inappropriate*. That word has a negative connotation to it that I don't get from *irrelevant*.)

That left me only with *everywhere and nowhere*.

When I hear *everywhere and nowhere*, I think to myself *unhelpful* and *meaningless*.  Those are at least close to *irrelevant*—and certainly closer, in my mind, than any of the other options.

But, as I say, it's more a process of elimination for me than an affirmative statement. (A kind of two-step equivalence.) *Everywhere and nowhere* is certainly not something that would leap into my mind as meaning *irrelevant*.

---

Having now composed my answer (not having wanted to have research affect my subjective response), I see that Merriam-Webster shows the following in its thesaurus for [*irrelevant*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/irrelevant):

> **Phrases Synonymous with IRRELEVANT**
>   beside the point, neither here nor there

I note that *neither here nor there* has almost the same meaning (or non-meaning) as *everywhere and nowhere*.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned "neither here or there" in my answer. That would have been my choice. But I cannot find "everywhere and nowhere" with that meaning.

Comment: +1 My thought process exactly.

Comment: The question is asking you to think like whoever prepared the exam. Looks to me like English is not their first language. Might as well check "dark matter" as well as "everywhere and nowhere", but the later is the only vaguely correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have picked the correct answer, 'everywhere and nowhere' because the other options are all wrong.

I came here because I was using this exact expression to describe the bitcoin network, I'm not exactly sure if it's the correct use so I searched the internet for an answer.

The way I have always understood this expression (as a native English, English speaker) is that the 'thing' you are describing is everywhere and at the same time, can't be seen or found and is therefore apparently nowhere.

The bitcoin network is everywhere but if you wanted to shut it down, you wouldn't be able to find it and therefore, from your perspective it's nowhere.

I would say things like government surveillance is also everywhere and nowhere. It is everywhere but at the same time from your perspective, it's nowhere.

To actually answer the question... in a sense, I would argue that it does mean irrelevant, such as: It is all around you, but it can't be seen and there is nothing you can do about it so therefore you can consider it irrelevant. Don't waste your time on things that you cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

No, ***everywhere and nowhere*** doesn't mean ***irrelevant*** (that's ***neither here nor there***).

Obviously at the *superficial semantic level* it's a kind of oxymoron / paradox, but *in practice*, it's been used over centuries to mean ***present*** everywhere, but **noticed** nowhere - when referring to how God manifests Himself in the world of men, for example.

More recently, it's also often used to mean *disorganized, lacking focus or direction*. To my mind...

> *He's **everywhere and nowhere***
>    **=**
>    *He's **all over the place*** (agitated, but lacking focus)
>    **+**
>    *He's **getting nowhere*** (trying, but achieving nothing)

Answer (score -1):

When I hear "everywhere and nowhere" I tend to think of it as meaning 'unpredictable.' But, basically, I'd argue that the test question is inappropriate (because it's confusing and basically nonsensical).

Comment: Hi Joel, welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately, the system has flagged your post as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." I recommend you [edit] your answer to respond directly to the question "Is the answer “everywhere and nowhere” ... **right or wrong**? Please provide **supporting evidence**" [my emphasis]. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)